# Mockito+Kotlin: How to mock a method that return T by callback

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

Im trying to create mock method to run Unit test for function below:

```
class SomeClass{
    fun <T> someMethod(str: String, action: (String) -> T): T {
        // do something
        return action(str);
    }
}
```

My mock method:

```
val mock = Mockito.mock(SomeClass::class.java)
`when`(mock.someMethod<Unit>(anyString(), any())).then { invocation ->
     @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
     (invocation.arguments[1] as (String) -> Unit).invoke("Some String...")
 }
```

but I meet the following issue, when running it failed and throw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException at line "`when`(mock.someMethod(anyString(), any())).then { invocation ->"

do you have any idea to fix it?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Using Mockito directly from Kotlin is annoying, e.g. because `when` is a keyword in the language and you have to escape it using backticks. There is a wrapper library which fixes most of the issues: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin. Otherwise, mockk is a good alternative mocking framework as well.

Regarding your problem:
It is probably related to the fact that Mockito and Kotlin don't work too well together; it works for me using the library mentioned above. Can you share more information about the error message?